# Need in SQL parser on Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird

Does anybody know about good SQL parser with sources, written in Delphi? I need in parsing SQL commands (with all new features of Firebird 2.5) into object structure.

Answer (score 4):

Read this article for [Delphi SQL Parser](http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/db/sql_parser/sql_parser.html), it uses IB as database but should not be very different between it and FB.

And there's an open source project called [SQL Parser for Delphi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gasqlparser/) but hasn't updated since 2005, but it may give you start up point.

Answer (score 2):

2 other native Delphi SQL parsers:

- [Zeoslib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib) seems to have an sql parser to parse Interbase, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, SqLite and Sybase.
- [General SQL Parser](http://www.sqlparser.com/download.php) (commercial)