# SQL Validation in Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, validation

I want to be able to check if SQL is valid e.g.

```
select * from contacts where id = 42
```

would pass but

```
select * from contacts where id 42
```

would fail

Does anyone know of a simple SQL Validation library - preferably free (or inexpensive)?

I want to do this as part of some unit testing, so I'm wanting to check if the generated SQL is valid, but don't want to execute it on a server.

Comment: Did you see [Need in SQL parser on Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615608/need-in-sql-parser-on-delphi?rq=1) and it's answers? Also, what database? Different DBMSs use different syntax, so any vaidator/parser would need to know what DBMS you are using to know what's valid.

Comment: @KenWhite Basic SQL92 syntax is fine, don't require any extensions for a particular DBMS

Comment: If you were working on SQL Server and would be able to be connected at the query validation, you might use the [`SET PARSEONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178629.aspx) statement.

Comment: @TLama Would still not be suitable for unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google query for "delphi sql parser" returns [this article](http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/db/sql_parser/sql_parser.html) on writing a SQL parser in Delphi, including source in a link at the bottom.

A parser can easily be used as a validator; just throw the generated output away.  If it parses, it's valid. If it errors out, it's not.

Comment: This parser looks like it might be usable, it does however call halt(1) if it encounters an error.  I was hoping to not have to spend much time working on this.  It also wont compile under XE3 as it is not Unicode aware.